# matplotlib bar chart auto-normalized my data

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I plotted a bar chart in what I thought was a rather standard way, but it seems like plt has normalized it automatically and either I suck at Google or there's not many posts on how to ummm...prevent this? Help much apprecited. kthxbyee.

```
obs_by_park = observations.groupby('park_name').sum().observations
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11, 8.5))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot()
ax1.bar(range(len(obs_by_park)), obs_by_park)
ax1.set_xticks(range(len(obs_by_park)))
ax1.set_xticklabels(observations.park_name.unique(), rotation=15)
plt.savefig('observations.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: it gave me this error: AttributeError: This method only works with the ScalarFormatter

Comment: needed to specify axis='y'. this answered it. thank you so much!